# Jupyter notebook API to get notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have my jupyter hub and single-user server running. I am using Jupyter notebook REST APIs to get all available notebooks. I am using http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/api/contents . With this I am able to see all available notebooks on mu UI.

However when I try to do the same from my python script I am getting 200 response code but unable to extract any content as its redirecting to login page where I need to enter username and password for my user. I also tried to pass these credentials through requests package. Something like this

```
import requests
api_url =  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/api/contents'
result = requests.get(api_url, auth=('username', 'password'))
print result
print result.json()
```

The outpus is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Jupyter Hub</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/hub/static/css/style.min.css?v=d96e0760e0c2b7356ce89635b646c350" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="/hub/static/components/requirejs/require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      require.config({

          urlArgs: "v=(&#39;20170907062813&#39;,)",

          baseUrl: '/hub/static/js',
          paths: {
            components: '../components',
            jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery.min',
            bootstrap: '../components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
            moment: "../components/moment/moment",
          },
          shim: {
            bootstrap: {
              deps: ["jquery"],
              exports: "bootstrap"
            },
          }
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.jhdata = {
        base_url: "/hub/",
        prefix: "/",

      }
    </script>




</head>

<body>

<noscript>
  <div id='noscript'>
    Jupyter Hub requires JavaScript.<br>
    Please enable it to proceed.
  </div>
</noscript>

<div id="header" class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
  <span id="jupyterhub-logo" class="pull-left"><a href="/hub/"><img src='/hub/logo' alt='JupyterHub' class='jpy-logo' title='Home'/></a></span>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="login-main" class="container">

<form action="/hub/login?next=%2Fhub%2Fuser%2Fpnda%2Fapi%2Fcontents" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="auth-form-header">
    Sign in
  </div>
  <div class='auth-form-body'>

    <p id='insecure-login-warning' class='hidden'>
    Warning: JupyterHub seems to be served over an unsecured HTTP connection.
    We strongly recommend enabling HTTPS for JupyterHub.
    </p>


    <label for="username_input">Username:</label>
    <input
      id="username_input"
      type="username"
      autocapitalize="off"
      autocorrect="off"
      class="form-control"
      name="username"
      val=""
      tabindex="1"
      autofocus="autofocus"
    />
    <label for='password_input'>Password:</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      name="password"
      id="password_input"
      tabindex="2"
    />

    <input
      type="submit"
      id="login_submit"
      class='btn btn-jupyter'
      value='Sign In'
      tabindex="3"
    />
  </div>
</form>

</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="error-dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="error-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="error-label">Error</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

  <div class="ajax-error">
    The error
  </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
if (window.location.protocol === "http:") {
  // unhide http warning
  var warning = document.getElementById('insecure-login-warning');
  warning.className = warning.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, '');
}
</script>



</body>

</html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    check_running()
  File "test.py", line 28, in check_running
    contents = r.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 740, in json
    return json.loads(self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

I am fairly new to Jupyter. My I missing out on something. How else can I authenticate my user prior calling any API.

Saw this in jupyerhub documentation - Note that the API token authorizes JupyterHub REST API requests. The same token does not authorize access to the Jupyter Notebook REST API provided by notebook servers managed by JupyterHub. A different token is used to access the Jupyter Notebook API.

So this is the exactly what I am looking for. How can I create this different token so as to access jupyter notebook APIs thorugh hub.

Comment: Does this run the notebook too before sending back html?

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter Notebooks require an access token (this should show when you start up jupyter notebook). In my case, something like this, then worked:

```
import requests
#Note that the url doesn't have a user or username attribute
api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/contents'
payload = {'token': 'xxxxxx'}
result = requests.get(api_url 
                  #, auth=('username', 'password')
                 ,params = payload)
```

Comment: I tried to create access token using jupterhub token <user> command for which i got no such user error. I also tried adding my user to admin_users and whitelist users in jupyterhub config

Comment: Are you able to view it as a json if you supply your api_url in the format I used i.e. without the 'user/username' path?

Comment: I am able to see the content on browser. How can i access jupter notebook apis through jupyter hub

Comment: I have come across this in jupyterhub doc "Note that the API token authorizes JupyterHub REST API requests. The same token does not authorize access to the Jupyter Notebook REST API provided by notebook servers managed by JupyterHub. A different token is used to access the Jupyter Notebook API." So this is my exact issue. How to create this different API token? To access notebook APIs. Do I access them through hub or what exactly